# Display Month window on calender popup for Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code in which we have to select year, month, date when we click on calendar icon for Mozilla Firefox.

Please suggest a way to display specified date's month-window.

So that we can just select date, instead of going all way down through year, month, date.

> Note: It's working like charm in other browsers except Mozilla

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
<input type="date" value="2017-05-24"/>
```

CODE Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BMEc9/2503/

Comment: Not sure if Mozilla works with "-" in the date. Try changing value="2017-05-24" to value="2017/05/24".  Other browser should accept this format.

Comment: @SiobhanBurke nope still same

Comment: I assume by "Mozilla," you mean "Firefox." Firefox doesn't provide a date-picker control for date inputs. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: @TiesonT. it doesn't, so to bypass that have used jquery here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
<input type="date" data-date='{"startView": 2}' value="2017-05-24"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type="date" value="2017-05-24"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BMEc9/2505/

Comment: Awesome, it's working! Can you explain about " data-date='{"startView": 2}' " ?

Comment: "startView":1 for year view, "startView":2 for month view and "startView":3 for day view